# Getting angularJS autcomplete in Webstorm/PHPStorm

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm

How do I get auto-complete for angularjs syntax in strings. For example:

**`myscript.js`**

```
var List = function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        "Ahmed",
        "Tom",
        "David",
        "Jessie"
    ];
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label for="get_name">
        Find your name:
        <input type="search" name="search" id="search" ng-model="search"/>
    </label>
</div>

<div ng-controller="List">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">{{ name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular_1.0.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

This is basically a way to search to names. How do I get auto-complete to appear inside `<li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">{{ name }}</li>` inside `ng-repeat`.

I am using PHPStorm 6.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't already have angular set up, go to Preferences > Project Settings > Javascript > Libraries and add your version of angular.

As for autocomplete in html strings, I don't think that's going to happen with the current version of PHPStorm, but in most other places, it should do the trick.

Comment: I'd suggest trying PHPStorm 8 EAP - AngularJS support has been improved there (see http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/phpstorm-8-early-access-program-started/)

Comment: I've installed both Angular library and AngularJS plugin, but I can't get the autocompletion to work. Any other idea of why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use awesome AngularJS plugin from John Lindquist.
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971

Comment: I've installed both Angular library and AngularJS plugin, but I can't get the autocompletion to work. Any other idea of why?

Answer (score 3):

I've finally got it to work by following **[this tutorial from JetBrains](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/05/angularjs-support-in-phpstorm/)**' blog.

**Short answer:**

You have two options to enable AngularJS autocomplete:

1. **Download** angular source code and put the file into a folder inside your project. (it wasn't working form me because I was using it direct from a CDN).
2. **If using a CDN**, you must go to Project Settings | JavaScript | Libraries | Download, then select *TypeScript community stub* from the select box on top left, find `angularjs` and `angular-ui` on the list, then *Download and install*.

Restart IDE. Be happy.

Answer (score 3):

In my case installing angular library didn't work. It was the angular plugin that did the trick. According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41qSD6gFwzs), install the angular plugin and restart your IDE.
For latest versions, you go to

**File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install JetBrains Plugin -> Search for the plugin, select and install**.

Finally, restart your IDE. You can test it by creating a div and typing ng- and you'll see all the suggestions.

Hope this helps.